# POST request to the WCF service by the use of HttpWebRequest

Tags: wcf

My Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITsdxService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="/GetTestCostCentre")]
    CostCentre GetTestCostCentre();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/SetCostCentre", Method="POST")]
    string SetCostCentre(CostCentre cc);
}

public class TsdxService : ITsdxService
{
    public CostCentre GetTestCostCentre()
    {
        CostCentre cc = new CostCentre();
        cc.Code = "Test";
        cc.Name = "Test Cost Centre";
        cc.Description = new byte[] { 12, 34, 89, 240, 66, 87, 189 };
        cc.SAPStatus = "Existent";
        cc.SAPSiteFolder = "Folder1";
        return cc;
    }

    public string SetCostCentre(CostCentre cc)
    {
        return cc.Code;
    }
}
```

Then I start this service and try to work with it from different application:

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri(textBox1.Text + "/tsdx/GetTestCostCentre");

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri) as HttpWebRequest;
XElement root;

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    root = XElement.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
    textBox2.Text = root.ToString();
}
```

All is ok, I am getting the xml document. But I've faced with problem when I tried to send POST request to this service:

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri(textBox1.Text + "/tsdx/SetCostCentre");

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri) as HttpWebRequest;

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    textBox2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Exception: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Why exactly you're not using the AddServiceReference in VisualStudio and use the generated proxy. I'm asking this because you're using C# for client side...

Comment: @Beygi Our client will use Java for this, and I just want to test this service by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your client code like this

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"<CostCentre xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCF_BadRequestService"">
                                                      <Code>String content</Code>
                                                      <Description>QmFzZSA2NCBTdHJlYW0=</Description>
                                                      <Name>String content</Name>
                                                      <SAPSiteFolder>String content</SAPSiteFolder>
                                                      <SAPStatus>String content</SAPStatus>
                                                    </CostCentre>");

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

Now it's fine.

And also i think Java supports WCF BasicHttpBinding, and you can use WCF services using the Java provided tools to generate web-service proxy in an easy supported manner.

Comment: Wow, very very thanks!! Now I see that the problem was that I din't add `request.ContentType = "application/xml";` string.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might want to do is to extend ClientBase to do all the hard work of serializing xml for you. Especially if you want to support more than one message format like json it will make your life a lot easier plus it will make any changes to the interface compile time errors instead of runtime errors.

```
public class ITsdxServiceProxy : ClientBase<ITsdxService>, ITsdxService {

    #region ITsdxService Members

    public CostCentre GetTestCostCentre() {
        return Channel.GetTestCostCentre();
    }

    public string SetCostCentre(CostCentre cc) {
        return Channel.SetCostCentre(cc);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

usage on client side

```
var proxy = new ITsdxServiceProxy();
var costCenter = proxy.GetTestCostCentre();
```

Configuration on client side

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>

  <endpoint 
            address="Root address for rest service"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="web"
            contract="FullyQualifiedNameOfInterface.ITsdxService">
  </endpoint>    

</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```